# Google Analytics registering Sessions but not Pageviews (4,402 sessions vs 0 pageviews)

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I can't figure out an issue I'm having on a client account.

I have GA installed via GTM. It appears to be triggering correctly.

[image]

But over in GA, it appears that it's registering Sessions but not Pageviews.

[image]

As a consequence, I'm seeing 4,402 sessions under Audience > Overview, Acquisition > Overview and I'm seeing sessions under Real-Time. But Behavior > Overview is giving me little data. Behavior > Landing Pages is showing all sessions as "(not set)".

How do I fix and/or troubleshoot this?

*updating to include GA debugging info*

Here's what I get out of the GA Chrome Debugging extension. Looks good to my eyes...

[image]

Comment: Install this chrome extension, enable it, load a page on your website and see what it says: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en

Comment: Just added a screenshot above. Looks okay to me?

Comment: Do you have any filters applied to the view?

Comment: Nope. I've got a raw data view without any filters that's having this happen. I have other views that do have filters, but since the non-filtered version is effective haven't dug into whether my filters are messing stuff up.

Answer (score 2):

To wrap this up, I figured it out.

The GTM UA pageview tag wasn't firing. It was never published. I was looking at the preview in google tag manager which is why everything appeared to be working correctly. It never occurred to me it never went live. (oops!)

Sessions triggered whenever a user clicked something because that sort of event was set up in GTM, but none of the page info was being pushed into GA.

And thats how you get sessions with no pageviews in Google Analytics.